# Sequences in infinite series

Tags: calculus

[image]

Hi! I have been working on a some online calculus2 sequence homework problems and I am having some issues with this one particular problem. I was able to solve A sub n of (n+1)/(n+3) to equal 1. So I was pretty confident that my answer to part A and B were correct, but I was not sure if my answer to part C was correct (if it is incorrect then the program will mark all of my answers incorrect as well). I would really appreciate it if someone can explain how to answer part C or explain if any of my other answer are incorrect. Thank you so much for your time and help!

Comment: Are you allowed to ask for outside help (e.g. the post here) on this problem? It looks like homework that you're graded on ("You can earn partial credit on this problem").

Answer (score 1):

In part c), you have / 1 - (n+1)/(n+3) / < t  <===> 2/(n+3) < t  <===> n+3 > 2/t <===>

n > 2/t - 3. So M = 2/t - 3.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I went back and plugged in your answer for M and it was correct but my answers to part A and B are still coming up wrong. So I was wondering if you could possibly help me out with those too, because I am not really sure why those answers are incorrect.

Comment: @user124539: for a) use t = 0.001 ==> M > 2000 - 3 = 1997. So choose M = 1998, and b) use t = 0.00001 ==> M > 200,000 - 3 = 199,997. Choose M = 199,998.

Comment: thank you so much for all of your help, I understand what i did wrong now.